# What happend to the tar.gz version of Java for Windows?

Tags: java

I used to be able to download a tar.gz version of the Java 8 JRE for Windows, now there is only the installer version. Does anybody know what happened to this or if there is another **official** Java "portable" download?

Edit: Same goes for Mac OS X, is there a tar.gz version of the Mac version of Java as well?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found it. The JDK doesn't have a tar.gz, but the JRE does.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html